# Conditional card drawing probability question

Tags: probability, summation, conditional-probability

Mary has a deck of $x$ cards of only two types. There are $y$ cards of the first type and $z$ cards of the second type.

If Mary draws $n$ cards before Sarah draws $m$ cards from the same deck (without replacement of cards), what are the chances of Mary having at least a quantity $q$ of the first type of cards if she draws another $t$ cards from the deck?

I am thinking that this question could be solved with the following function:

$$ \sum_{k=q_2}^t \sum_{j=0}^m \sum_{i=q_1}^n \left ( \frac{\binom{y}{i} \cdot \binom{z}{n-i}}{\binom{x}{n}} \right ) \left ( \frac{\binom{y-i}{j} \cdot \binom{x-y+i-n}{m-j}}{\binom{x-n}{m}} \right ) \left ( \frac{\binom{y-i-j}{k} \cdot \binom{x-y+i-n+j-m}{t-k}}{\binom{x-n-m}{t}} \right ) $$

in all cases in which $q_1 + q_2\geq q$.

As you can see, the problem is that multiple summation functions cannot calculate conditional probability because they do not multiply each new case by the previous cases from which it is conditional upon.

Any way you can define a new function for the benefit of all humanity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

If I understand well (Mary takes $n$ cards without replacement. Then Sarah takes $m$ cards from the *remaining* cards without replacement. Then Mary takes $t$ cards again from the remaining cards without replacement) then you can rephrase the question:

"What are the chances of Mary having at least a quantity $q$ of the first type of cards if she draws in total $n+t$ cards from the deck?"

Comment: Does Sarah draw the $m$ cards from the cards that **remain** after the first turn of Mary? And secondly does Mary in her second turn draw cards that remain after the (first) turn of her and Sarah?

Comment: @Student13 so what? Mary always takes $n+t$ cards from fixed positions in the deck; assuming the deck is shuffled it doesn't matter what those positions are.

Comment: Yes, Sarah draws the m cards that remain after the first turn of Mary, and Mary in her second turn draw cards that remain after the first turn of her and Sarah. As a result, with each turn, the number of cards in the deck decreases and the probabilities change. Additionally, because there are two types of cards, there are multiple cases of varying numbers of these two types of cards after each player's turn.

Comment: For simplicity let it be that $m=n=t=1$. Label the cards with $1,2,3,\dots$. In this case Mary takes cards $1$ and $3$. What is the difference with taking $1$ and $2$? Has card $2$ a larger (or smaller) probability than card $3$ to be a card from the first type?...Definitely not!

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem isn't so simple. In the case you have outlined, the cases in brackets separated by a comma of the quantities of type y cards drawn by each player are (0,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,1,0), (0,1,1), (1,0,0), (1,0,1), (1,1,0), and (1,1,1). Already, there are three different probabilities of Mary drawing a type y card during her second turn. This is because, even though there are the same number of cards remaining in the deck in each case, the number of type y cards could have been reduced by either 0, 1, or 2 by the time Mary makes her second turn.

Comment: The events $(0,0,1)$, $(0,1,0)$ and $(1,0,0)$ have *the same probability*. So do the events $(0,1,1)$, $(1,0,1)$ and $(1,1,0)$. Consequently the probability that the second coördinate equals $n\in\{0,1\}$ is same as the probability that  the third coördinate equals $n$. Ask yourself this question: If there is a normally shuffled deck of cards labeled with a number (eventually from top to bottom), then is there a difference between the probability that the card with label $2$ is an ace and the probability that the card with label $3$ is an ace?

Comment: Indeed, what you said is correct. However, while the cases of (0,0,1) and (1,0,0) result in Mary having at least 1 card of type y, the case of (0,1,0) does not. This is why each case is conditional upon the previous one.

Comment: As you can see, whether Mary has the specified quantity of cards is conditional upon what cards Sarah draws

Comment: Something like "Sarah draws $m$ cards had $u$ of them are of the first type" would indeed be a condition that should be taken into account. But purely "Sarah draws $m$ cards" is not a condition that needs to be taken into account. As @EspeciallyLime commented: "so what?..." I advice you to read his comment again.

Comment: Hey man, thanks so much. I finally understand now. This question only applies if the deck gets shuffled after each turn, right?